# Как из datagridview считать значения в одномерный массив?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Здесь я создал массив, и сделал цикл `for` чтобы считать строки чисел который пользователь ввел в `DataGridView` и сохранить в массив

[image]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double[] Main = {};
            
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        Main[i] = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вставьте код текстом вместо скриншота.

Comment: Чтобы понять как что-то прочитать из таблицы, надо понять, как это "что-то" туда попало.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас добавлю

Comment: `double[] Main = { };` - вы создали массив размером 0.

Comment: Да, без указания размера и єлементов в нем, задумка чтоб пользователь написал числа в датагрид

Comment: Подчеркивает Value, я подумал возможно не то с приведением типов и добавил к Value.ToString() - ошибка компилятора пропала но данные в массив не сохраняет

Comment: Массивы в C# имеют фиксированный размер, который задается при его создании. Когда вы пишете `double[] Main = { };` - вы делаете массив, который рассчитан на 0 элементов, и если вы обращаетесь например к первому (`Main[0]` (отсчет в программировании с 0) ), то вы получаете ошибку, ибо массив не имеет такого индекса. Если вы сделаете `double[] Main = new double[1];`, то будет массив на 1 элемент, тогда код `Main[0]` сработает, а вот `Main[1]` (взять второй) нет, ибо массив рассчитан всего на 1 объект. Так что, задайте верный размер, либо используйте коллекции (`List<>` например), они динамичны.

Comment: Понял, спасибо вам

Comment: Также отмечу, что в коде на скрине каждое следующее значение из массива заменяет собой текущее в текстбоксе.

Answer (score 0):

Значения в `DatagridView` хранятся в табличном виде. Чтобы считать значение из ячейки, нужно обратиться к ней напрямую

```
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        //инициализация массива
        var Main = new double[dataGridView1.Rows.Count][];
        //проходим по строкам
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            Main[i] = new double[row.Cells.Count];
            //проход по столбцам строки
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                //проверяем, последняя строка у DGV пустая
                if (cell.Value != null)
                {
                    Main[i][j] = double.Parse(cell.Value.ToString());
                    j++;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Также нужно сделать проверку, что пользователь вводит именно числа, но это вы уже сможете сами (например методом `TryParse`)
Добавил инициализацию массива и индексы для понятного итерирования.

Ну и для вывода всего массива в тест, его нужно преобразовать в строку. Например так:

```
            string[] strArray = new string[Main.Count()];
            for (int i = 0; i < Main.Count(); i++)
            {
                strArray[i] = string.Join(", ", Main[i]);
            }
```

Comment: Вы забыли упомянуть, что перед этим стоит создать массив, в котором будет достаточно места для добавления элементов. Если создать массив так же как это сделал автор в вопросе, то ничего в него положить не получится. Предлагаю дополнить ответ.